# Activate GRUB recordfail in Fedora

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2

Some distros like Ubuntu can automatically show grub options after a system failure.

How can I activate `GRUB recordfail` feature in Fedora, Like seen in other distros like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point, I discovered it is a Ubuntu and derivatives only feature unfortunately.